# subversion install from source - http unrecognized url scheme

Tags: linux, svn, http, https

I am installing subversion from source.  I downloaded neon, and extracted it to my subversion directory.  Then did

```
make clean
./configure --with-gnome-keyring --with-ssl
make
make install
```

Still, the svn client that is built, does not support HTTP or HTTPS url scheme. How to fix?

Comment: Fixed it. I need to configure and install neon separately (one post on the internet said I just need to place neon source folder in subversion before configuring/making subversion... but that does not work).